# Google Script how to send email based on ONE cell being edited

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need help with this code. It's working how I want except it sends me emails when ALL the cells get edited in the row. I just want to know when the one cell in column C gets edited and to send an email based on that edit. Here is what I have:

```
function go(e) {
  // Fetch the monthly sales
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("C3:C"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (monthSales > 1){
  var rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][2];
  let d = new Date(rData[0][0]).toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  let items = rData[0][3];
  let loc = rData[0][1];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  let b = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1").getValues();
  
  let msg = " (" + d + ") Enter warehouse location for " + n + " " + items + " Requested by " + loc + " " + now;
  GmailApp.sendEmail("myemailaddress", b + " Entered a Request", msg)
}
}
```

Can someone please help me figure this out. I just want to be notified when the last row in column C has been edited and send an email based on that edit.

Answer (score 0):

To stop sending the emails when column C was not edited, you might add `if(e.range.columnStart !== 3) return;` after `function go(e){`

To stop sending the emails when the last row of column C was not edited add `if(!(e.range.getSheet().getLastRow() === e.range.rowStart e.range.columnStart === 3)) return;` after `function go(e){`